# How to pass parameter from Express to Angular 6?

Tags: node.js, express, routes, angular6

How can I pass parameter from Express route to A

```
`router.post('/login',
    passport.authenticate('local', { failureRedirect: '/login' }),
    function(req, res) {
        res.locals.username=req.user.username;
        res.redirect('/home');
    });`
```

This is what I have in the route for Express. I want to pass the username from here to the frontend that I have done in Angular and echo it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should return a **JSON** versus **redirects** and in the front-end side catch the response to render it.

```
router.post('/login', function(req, res, next) {
    passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user, info) {
        if (err) {
            return res.json({ error: err });
        }
        if (!user) {
             return res.json({ error: 'Authentication failed' });
        }
        req.logIn(user, function(err) {
            if (err) {
                return res.json(err);
            }
            return res.json({ username: user.username });
        });
    })(req, res, next);
});
```

I based in the **Passport** docs in the **Authentication / Custom Callback** section:
http://www.passportjs.org/docs/